# php & mysql: Echo'ed table values cannot be re-inserted?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table list of ingredients, which has about 5-6 values like cost, store, packaging, quanity, ect.

I then echo the data from the tables onto a drop down menu so they are selectable. However when I go to update or re-insert them into a new table, I get a error messaging saying "cost is not defaulted", even though it is.

So basically what is happening, is my drop down menu is NOT the database value itself when its time to use it to update it into a new table. Its stringified and its value is completely new. Is there a way to stop this from happening and tell mysql or PHP that I want the database values I originally put in when selected and not a stringified version of it?

```
<select name="ingredients_list" placeholder="Ingredients">
<option disabled selected value> -- select an ingredient -- </option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT item, store
            FROM ingredients
            ORDER BY item";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($col = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  "<option>" . $col['item'] . " (" . $col['store'] . ") " . "</option>";
    }
} 
    ?>
```

Error Message:

```
Error: INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (meal_name, item) VALUES ('turkey', 'Bacon (Lidl)')
Field 'package' doesn't have a default value
```

It DOES have a value, but its not using it because its using the stringified "bacon" of the drop down, rather than the data on the database itself.

Comment: you haven't executed your query for a start..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert  only a part of the values  for the table  columns .. one of this column  named  `package`  have a not null constrains so the partial  insert

```
INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (meal_name, item) VALUES ('turkey', 'Bacon (Lidl)')
```

don't  respect this constrain

could be you need

```
INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (meal_name, item,package )
        VALUES ('turkey', 'Bacon (Lidl)', 'my_package_value')
```